# Git - re-add files under a lower case namespace name

Tags: c#, git, github

I have a C# project in dotnet standard which I am tracking in Git & Github.

At some point I renamed a project which had an unnecessary captial letter in the name, but this left two distinct top-level namespaces - one with the capital and without, like the 'L' in the following example.

..src/MyProject.CapitalLetter

..src/MyProject.Capitalletter

Now when my pull requests are pulled into master on Github there are two projects for this - one with the capital letter and one without. If I run:

```
git ls-files
```

I can see that it is tracking some under a fully qualified name with the capital still, even though everything in Visual Studio is now lowercase. How can I update how git is tracking them?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to something else and then back? Or perhaps `git mv old_filename new_filename`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by running:

```
git rm --cached src/MyProject.CapitalLetter.SomeProjectName/*
```

and then:

```
git add .
```

Basically untracked all the gammy files and then retracked them.